# Create vector of duplicate objects?

Tags: c++, object, vector

I have a vector with a size of 50, inside the vector is 5 objects. I want to copy all the contents from these 5 objects and fill the rest of the vector with them.

What I have below copies the objects exactly (the i=5 is because I am ignoring the first 4 vector elements).

```
for (int i = 5; i <= CParams::iNumBirds; i++){
    m_vpDisplayableObjects[i + 5] = m_vpDisplayableObjects[i];
}
```

But the problem is I want to give each object a different ID, 0-50. See below

```
for (int i = 0; i < CParams::iNumBirds; i++) {
        m_pMainEngine->GetDisplayableObject(i + 5)->ObjectID = i;
    }
```

Obviously since they are copies, every 5 elements resets the ObjectID, so in the end all objects have and ID of 45-50 not 0-50.

My question is, how can I create copies of these objects but give each one a different ObjectID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function that copy the attributes values of the copied object to a new object and pass the id of the new object as parameter.

```
 Obj copy(Obj& obj, int id) {
     Obj newObj();
     // copy atributes
     newObj.attribute1 = obj.attribute1;
     //...
     newObj.ObjectID = id;
     return newObj;
}
```

Then call this function in the for loop

```
for (int i = 5; i <= CParams::iNumBirds; i++){
    m_vpDisplayableObjects[i + 5] = copy(m_vpDisplayableObjects[i], i + 5);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the same problem occurs, if I change the ID here, the IDs will just be the most recent 5. It wont start at 0 because they are duplicates so when the latest duplicate is given an ID it will overwrite all the previous ones

Comment: Now I get it. So you need to create a new object with the same attributes values of the original.

Comment: if you found this useful also voteup and mark the question as answered

Comment: So I have to manually copy each attribute over, even if there are 100s of attributes?

Comment: As far as I know, yes